# Creating Theme Settings Page

Tags: theme-development, options

I am trying to create a custom theme settings page for a wordpress theme, so that I may hopefully continue to reuse it on the future websites I make. Unfortunately, I'm falling at the first hurdle. I'm attempting to add the page to the menus using this code :

```
add_menu_page('Theme Settings', 'Theme Settings', 'manage_options', 'kitleyhouse/ether_settings.php');
```

But I can't seem to get it to let me use an actual PHP file (not just a function) for the page content. It would be much easier, and nicer to work on if I could contain all the files for the settings page within a subfolder in my theme (e.g. themename/admin-settings/ or something). The menu item is being displayed in the admin panel, however when clicked it takes you to a 404 page.

I have the file currently stored in the root of my theme folder (I started out with it in a subfolder). I have tried putting just the file name, the theme folder name and filename (as shown), I've tried pulling in the full theme URI, and using get_bloginfo('template_url'), get_theme_root... EVERYTHING I could think of, but no one else seems to be having this problem.

So am I just being a massive idiot, or is there some other problem I'm not seeing.

Thanks you in advance, this has caused me such a headache.

Comment: I'm a little rusty, but why not group all your theme options page functions into one file, load them in the plugin and then you can use the function reference to load it? See: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/ (this is a very good tutorial that will help with the tougher bits of option page creation)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was using a much older tutorial from tutsplus I believe. But unfortunately that's not the issue. I'm happy to have all of the theme setting functions together, but I'd like to have them outside of my functions.php

Comment: In order for WordPress to use them, you're going to need to include the PHP file through functions.php or a plugin - what use case does not having them in it satisfy? Edit: You can have them all in /theme-settings/settings.php and then just include them in the functions.php?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being very clear. I know it has to be included in the functions. I am happy to have the thing to add the page to the menu within the functions (and anything else that needs to be in there) but I want the HTML markup for the page to be stored within it's own file, which is in a subdirectory of a theme. The problem is, I don't know how to get the add_menu_page to point towards said separate files; no matter what I put in there (that I can think of) it just sends me to a 404.

Comment: Why not create the HTML markup and then in the theme function, include that page? That'll pull it in but store the file separately.

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to. I can't see how else to make this thing work like it appears to for plugins. I just wanted to create a nice modular theme settings system so I could use it in future projects too.

Comment: You can try using Redux framework [https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/] for Wordpress with a great variety of  fully responsive options, and also lets you test the framework in the real time. It’s a translation ready product, and you may also generate theme setting panel according to your need.